# why doesn't my nested insert statement work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
insert into myTable (Id) values (
       select id from someTable where seriesid not in (120, 130, 110, 300)
)
```

I get this error message in SSMS:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>       Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>       Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>       Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: its not nested insert....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you perform a `select` in an `insert` then you *may* skip the `values` part

```
insert into myTable (Id) 
select id 
from someTable 
where seriesid not in (120, 130, 110, 300)
```

Comment: *You can skip* - actually, no - you **must** skip the `values` clause

Comment: @marc_s That's incorrect.  You just need parentheses `declare @t table(i int); insert @t values(1),((select * from @t)),(2),((select 3))`